# Универсальный код для появления блоков по клику на radiobutton

Tags: javascript

Добрый вечер подскажите, нужно реализовать такую задачу, есть радио кнопки. При выборе определенного radiobuttona появляется блок с другими radio кнопками и в этом блоке при выборе другой определенной радио кнопки появляется еще один блок с такими же радио кнопками.
Вот есть скрипт который вроде по словам автора должен выполнять такую задачу, помогите настроить этот скрипт и написать под него структуру.

```
$('input.ShowOrHide').click(function() {
  var checked = $("input.ShowOrHide:checked");

  if (checked.length == 0) {
    var currentDiv = this.attr("class"); /* тут вроде как распарсить классы 
нужно и найти отвечающий за связующий с дивом. Все классы для js удобно 
именновать "имя_js"*/
    var getCurrentClass = имя_js_1 /*распарсить получить класс указывающий на 
нужный див(имя_js и див 1)*/
    var findDiv = "div.+currentDiv";

    $(findDiv).show();
  } else {
    $("div.ShowOrHide").hide();
    $('div#' + $(this).val()).show();

  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.b {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.b__input {
  display: none;
}

.b__label {
  display: block;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.b__label~.b__label {
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}

.b__input:checked+.b__label {
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: default;
}

.b__content {
  max-height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  transition: max-height .3s;
}

.b__input:checked+.b__label+.b__content {
  max-height: 500px;
  visibility: visible;
  transition-delay: 0;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="b">
  <input type="radio" class="b__input" name="nameRadio" id="r1">
  <label for="r1" class="b__label">title 1</label>
  <div class="b__content">content 1</div>

  <input type="radio" class="b__input" name="nameRadio" id="r2">
  <label for="r2" class="b__label">title 2</label>
  <div class="b__content">content 2</div>

  <input type="radio" class="b__input" name="nameRadio" id="r3">
  <label for="r3" class="b__label">title 3</label>
  <div class="b__content">content 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: сам аккордеон не нужен

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю как этот ваш `js` код работает. Но вот пример с чистым `css` который делает то что вы хотели. Просто надо знать [селекторы и псевдоклассы](https://learn.javascript.ru/css-selectors) `:checked` и `+`.

Ну а за стилизацию можете заняться вы сами)))

Если что то не получиться то тогда напишите вопрос со своим недостаточно хорошим кодом, поможем.

```css
input{
  float: left;
}
div{
  display: inline-block;
  //width: auto;
  height: 15px;
  max-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
input:checked + div{
  max-width: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="radioFirst" />
<input type="radio" name="radioFirst" />
<input type="radio" name="radioFirst" />
<div class="sub_1_radio">
  <input type="radio" name="radioSub1" />
  <input type="radio" name="radioSub1" />
  <input type="radio" name="radioSub1" />
  <div class="sub_2_radio">
    <input type="radio" name="radioSub2" />
    <input type="radio" name="radioSub2" />
    <input type="radio" name="radioSub2" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Надо чтоб когда ты выбираешь обратно тот радио button все назад скрывалось как и было.
Вот как на вот этом сайте http://muik.ru/calculator.php#
В аккордеоне есть пункт меню под названием "Раздел котельной",
там будет два пункта радио button один выбран, когда выберешь другой появляется и так далее как я описывал выше.

Comment: Интересно вы так плохо знаете `css`? Это просто пример, и в нем не было задано имена радиокнопок, вот задал имена, и все работает так как вы хотели.

Comment: нет смысл в том чтоб, это еще плюс ко всему было плавно стилей прийдется писать куча

Comment: @KirillTaran Все ровно нужно писать стили,сейчас сделаю это плавным, без `кучи` стилей.

Comment: Спасибо огромное